# JQuery Callback Never Called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS/JQuery snippet:

```
 function add_item() {
   var item = $("input:text[name='new_item']").val();
   $.post("{{ url_for('add_item') }}",
       {'item' : item},
       function(data) {
         alert(':}');
       });
 }
```

It performs a simple AJAX request to a Flask webserver and displays an alert box on success (the data always returns a JSON snippet).  The AJAX request adds a field to a SQLite database and returns.  On my dev box, this request completes very quickly using asynchronous requests.  However, on another server this request takes a few seconds (less than the default timeout, though) using asynchronous requests.

**Problem**: When the request takes a long time to complete using asynchronous requests, the callback is never called.  When I change the AJAX settings to be synchronous, the callback is always called.

Thank!

Comment: Have you checked if its timing out? Add a timeout handler and see if that gets called or increase the timeout and try. Also add an error handler to see if you're getting any errors.

Comment: I tried increasing the timeout - that didn't have any new affect.  The error handler *does* get called.

Comment: There you go. Since there is an error, your success handler doesn't get called.

Comment: How can I determine why the error method is getting called?  The same code works if I make the call synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the `$.ajax()` function over the post one. Seems to have been more maintained - 1.6.2 also seems to have some issues, so try 1.6.1 if you need to: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Use the error method to find out what error you're getting.

```
function add_item() {
   var item = $("input:text[name='new_item']").val();
   $.post("{{ url_for('add_item') }}",
       {'item' : item},
       function(data) {
         alert(':}');
       }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("error"); });
 }
```